# How to exclude a specific file from my bundle?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm using webpack for build my application (angular2/typescript) and I reach create two files, one for my code and one for vendors. But i want a third file for separate my config (principally for API_ENDPOINT) which is used directly in my code.

How can I use my config file (config.ts) for build my app with loaders but exclude it from the  generated Js file ?

**Currently**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <head>
      <base href="/configuration/" >
      <title>Gestion de la configuration technique</title>
      <meta charset=UTF-8>
      <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href=./assets/logo.png />
      <link href="vendor.841ccc40b7395ddc1da4.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="app.841ccc40b7395ddc1da4.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <sg-conf>loading ...</sg-conf>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.841ccc40b7395ddc1da4.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="app.841ccc40b7395ddc1da4.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Expected**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <head>
      <base href="/configuration/" >
      <title>Gestion de la configuration technique</title>
      <meta charset=UTF-8>
      <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href=./assets/logo.png />
      <link href="vendor.841ccc40b7395ddc1da4.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="app.841ccc40b7395ddc1da4.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <sg-conf>loading ...</sg-conf>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.841ccc40b7395ddc1da4.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="app.841ccc40b7395ddc1da4.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="config.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

The file i want to exclude from the app.js
**src/config.ts**

```
export class Config {
   static apiUrl = (process.env.ENV === "prod" ?  "xxxxxxx" : "http://localhost:8080/");
   static token = (process.env.ENV === "prod" ? "aaaaaa" : "bbbbb");
}
```

I merge two webpack config files, **first** :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts',
    'config' : './src/config.ts'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: [/*'console',*/  'awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
      { 
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, 
        loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
      },
      { 
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
         loader: "file-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: 'raw'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills', 'config']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' }
    ]),
  ],

  tslint: {
    "configuration" : {
      "extends": "tslint:recommended",
      "rulesDirectory": [
        "node_modules/codelyzer"
      ],
      "rules":{
        "directive-selector-name": [true, "camelCase"],
        "component-selector-name": [true, "kebab-case"],
        "directive-selector-type": [true, "attribute"],
        "component-selector-type": [true, "element"],
        "directive-selector-prefix": [true, "sg"],
        "component-selector-prefix": [true, "sg"],
        "use-input-property-decorator": true,
        "use-output-property-decorator": true,
        "use-host-property-decorator": true,
        "no-attribute-parameter-decorator": true,
        "no-input-rename": true,
        "no-output-rename": true,
        "no-forward-ref": true,
        "use-life-cycle-interface": true,
        "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
        "pipe-naming": [true, "camelCase", "sg"],
        "component-class-suffix": true,
        "directive-class-suffix": true,
        "import-destructuring-spacing": true,
        "templates-use-public": true,
        "no-access-missing-member": true,
        "invoke-injectable": true
      }
    },
    emitErrors: true,
    failOnHint: true,
    fileOutput: { 
      ext: "xml", 
      clean: true, 
      header: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<checkstyle version=\"5.7\">",
      footer: "</checkstyle>"
    }
  }
};
```

Second :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var WebpackBaseHref = require('webpack-base-href');
var helpers = require('./helpers');
var path = require('path');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'prod';

module.exports = [ webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: '',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
  },

  htmlLoader: {
    minimize: false // workaround for ng2
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
      mangle: {
        keep_fnames: true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'ENV': (ENV && JSON.stringify(ENV)) || 'prod'
      }
    }),
    new WebpackBaseHref.WebpackBaseHref({
      baseHref: '/configuration/'
    })
  ]
})];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a simple example and it generates correctly the bundles i asked for

### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname),
    entry: {
        'index': path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.js'),
        'config': path.join(__dirname, 'src/config.js')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /(\.js)|(\.jsx)$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
                }
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    }
};
```

### output in public directory

- config.bundle.js
- index.bundle.js

both have the content expected

If that doesnt help can you send me your config.ts
little precision i did in es6 if i have time i will do it in typescript to see if it can be linked to that but i doubt about it

Comment: I add my config.ts in the first post. I think the problem is due to typescript because the code in my app need the config.ts for trans-compile the code. Or maybe my class Config isn't expose as a module ?

Comment: Sorry i havnt seen it! Ok i will try to setup it and come back to you. But if you have the right typescript loader in webpack it has to work. Transpiling and generate bundle are different step.

Comment: You are right, transpiling and generate bundle are different step. I think the problem is due to my use of the webpack plugin CommonsChunkPlugin. If i delete it or if i leave just name: ['config', 'vendor', 'polyfills']  instead of  name: ['config', 'app', 'vendor', 'polyfills'], the output config.js file seem right.

Comment: It's work, but i have a last request. I want add hash in output filenames but not for the config.js. In my webpack config file, i use "filename: '[name].[hash].js',", how can i add a condition ? => "filename" : (([name] === 'config') ?  '[name].js' :  '[name].[hash].js')

Comment: Ah super, which fix did you apply? Ok let me take a look on that quickly

Comment: If CommonsChunkPlugin works fine, you can remove config.ts from your bundle and use it in CommonsChunkPlugin to be inserted in your html which will be used by your bundle. Like that config.ts wont have any hash code whereas all your entry point will have